# Garbage collection does not recognize del of a class after instance assignment

Tags: python, unit-testing, garbage-collection, subclassing

For testing purposes, I'm creating temporary classes which I want to delete (before other test methods run). Trouble is, `[superclass].__subclasses__()` still lists the deleted classes, even after running garbage collection.

Here's what my test method looks like:

```
class Apple(Fruit):
    @staticmethod
    def mass(size):
        return size

class Orange(Fruit):
    @staticmethod
    def mass(size):
        return size

try:
    Apple()
    Orange()
    a1 = Apple(type='fuji')
finally:
    if 'a1' in locals():
        print 'del a1'
        del a1
    print gc.get_referrers(Apple)
    print gc.get_referrers(Orange)
    del Apple
    del Orange
    print Fruit.__subclasses__()
    gc.collect()
    print Fruit.__subclasses__()
```

The output is as follows:

```
del a1
[<frame object at 0xabcdef0>, (<class 'Apple'>, <class 'Fruit'>, <type 'object'>), <Apple object at 0x4443331>, {'a1': <Apple object at 0x4443331, 'self': <FruitTests testMethod=test_pass_Fruit_core>, 'Orange': <class 'Orange'>, 'Apple': <class 'Apple'>}]    
[<frame object at 0xabcdef0>, (<class 'Orange'>, <class 'Fruit'>, <type 'object'>), {'a1': <Apple object at 0x4443331, 'self': <FruitTests testMethod=test_pass_Fruit_core>, 'Orange': <class 'Orange'>, 'Apple': <class 'Apple'>}]
[<class 'Apple'>, <class 'Orange'>]
[<class 'Apple'>, <class 'Orange'>]
```

None of the classes involved have an explicitly-defined `__del__()`, although `Fruit` does use `__metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta` and a `@abc.abstractmethod` decorator on `Fruit.mass()`.

The remaining class reference has something to do with the assignment of the `Fruit` instance to a variable: If I remove all the lines containing `a1`, the final `Fruit.__subclasses__()` returns `[]` - even though the bare constructor `Apple()` still runs.

This is a problem for me because another test is concerned with fruit interactions (call the relevant method-to-be-tested `blends()`), and that uses a `Fruit.__subclasses__()` call to check combinations of different types of `Fruit`. I haven't bothered to define interactions with these test classes, and that's confusing `blends()`.

Any hints on why these references are sticking around would be appreciated.

Edit: If I call gc.get_referrers(Apple) after gc.collect(), I get an "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Apple' referenced before assignment" Fruit defines a number of methods with the "@classmethod "and "@property" decorators, and references another class which handles "blends()"...

After garbage collection, `gc.get_referrers(Fruit.__subclasses__()[0])` returns

```
[{'a1': <Apple object at 0x4443331>, 'self': <FruitTests testMethod=test_pass_Fruit_core>, 'Orange': <class 'Orange'>, 'Apple': <class 'Apple'>}, <Apple object at 0x4443331>, (<class 'Apple'>, <class 'Fruit'>, <type 'object'>)]
```

Edit: The problem occurs when I run just this one test method. (It also occurs when I queue up multiple tests.) I tried rebooting my IDE (PyCharm) and running "./manage.py test FruitTests.test_pass_Fruit_core " from the command line. All cases yield the same results, although the particular memory addresses vary. locals() is being called directly - I don't have it aliased anywhere.

Edit: The entire module defining Fruit:

```
from abc import abstractmethod, ABCMeta


class Fruit(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Fruit, self).__init__()

    @abstractmethod
    def mass(self, size):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

In the test method, test_pass_Fruit_core(), "a1 = Apple()" and "a1 = Apple(type='fuji')" produce the same results. Dropping the assignment to "a1" makes no difference, but if I drop the call to "locals()", garbage collection works as expected - Apple is no longer available as a subclass of Fruit at the end of the method.

Comment: And what does `gc.get_referrers(Apple)` print after garbage collection?

Comment: The references to subclasses are weak references, so *something else* is still referring to these classes. The ABC architecture also holds references, again weak references are used.

Comment: Use `gc.gen_referrers(Fruit.__subclasses__()[0])`.

Comment: So, is there another `FruitTests.test_pass_Fruit_core` test method alive somewhere holding on to *another* set of these subclasses? Or did you store the output of `locals()` somewhere, that looks like a `locals()` dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The persistent reference is being created in the call to locals(). To guarantee "del a1" does not generate an error if one was created inside the "try:" block, assign "a1 = None" before the block and skip the call to locals().

Final, working code follows. Compare with the first code block above:
    class Apple(Fruit):
        @staticmethod
        def mass(size):
            return size

```
class Orange(Fruit):
    @staticmethod
    def mass(size):
        return size

a1 = None
try:
    Apple()
    Orange()
    a1 = Apple(type='fuji')
finally:
    del a1
    print gc.get_referrers(Apple)
    print gc.get_referrers(Orange)
    del Apple
    del Orange
    print Fruit.__subclasses__()
    gc.collect()
    sc = Fruit.__subclasses__()
    print sc
    if len(sc) > 0:
        print 42, gc.get_referrers(sc[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

In garbage collected environments object's life time **is not** your responsibility. And because of this, you shouldn't rely on that. Unit tests should test your business logic, each unit test should test one of unit's responsibilities. Object life time can't be their responsibility, and if your logic relies on it, then either you're using the wrong environment, or you're misusing your current environment.

Perhaps try to introduce a notion of an "active" `Fruit` in your implementation, using patterns like `Pool` or/and `Factory`. If you'll delete an object from your list of "active" object you won't have to worry about GS's "indeterminism".

Comment: It seems awkward to introduce an attribute which will only be used in the tests. The purpose of the above tests is to verify that the @abc.abstractmethod decorator is present and works as advertised. (That is, these classes should be instantiable if and only if the subclass provides an explicit definition of mass.)

Comment: @SarahMesser That looks again as trying to test something that isn't your responsibility. The `abc` module should have its own unit tests that prove its working correctly.